# Is HTTPS as the form's action enough?

Tags: html, http, forms, ssl, https

Is HTTPS as the (HTML) form's action enough for the form data to be SSL encrypted for submission?

Or does the page that hosts the form have to be HTTPS as well?

Comment: I ask because I see that Twitter's "Sign in" popup box launches from an HTTP page but actions to an HTTPS page. Got me wonderin' LOL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the page the form is hosted on is not served over HTTPS, then it can be intercepted and modified en route. These modifications can include such things as changing the action of the form, or adding JavaScript to send the data to a third party before submitting the form as normal.

Submitting the form over HTTPS is **not** sufficient to protect the data. The form needs to be delivered that way too.

Answer (score 4):

HTTPS on the form's action is sufficient to encrypt the form submission.

The page that hosts the form doesn't have to HTTPS, although it helps to give the users confidence that their data is secure.

The other benefit of securing the hosting page is that the form can't be spoofed or altered by a man-in-the-middle.

Comment: While it works, there are a bunch of reasons not to do, the right answer is while it is possible don't do it because the user is unaware.

Comment: @stephbu: Agreed - and I listed two of those reasons in my answer.

Comment: Hehe - my original comment was truncated - I'd put that I would have voted for @stian, being newer, but your customer focused reasons are far more accurate.

Comment: “other benefit” is an understatement! If the form action is spoofed, there is HTTPS after all. So it is **not** sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough if all you want to do is wave the magical encryption fairy dust around.  It's not enough if you want to actually be secure.  Any man-in-the-middle attack could simply rewrite the form HTML to post to a malicious server.